# How can I get truly random even distribution of GPS coordinates in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, geospatial

My first attempt produces points often near polar regions:

```
gps = {
    lat: (Math.random() * (90 - -90) + -90) * Math.PI / 180,
    lon: (Math.random() * (180 - -180) + -180) * Math.PI / 180,
    alt: 0
};
```

(yes I'm converting to radians)
I quickly realized that it's an uneven distribution.
According to this site https://dosull.github.io/posts/2021-10-20-random-even-points-on-the-globe/ I'll need to use some sort of "acos" (is that arccos?) function, but I don't even know what language that is. whuber's comment at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/236321/generating-random-lat-long-coordinates mentions *cosine* but I'm not sure exactly what the formula would be.

Comment: Why do you have to do this in *Javascript*? And yes, acos is arc-cosine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lat: Math.acos(Math.random() * 2 - 1) - Math.PI / 2,
```